# Libgdx; dispose() Box2D World and Renderer

Tags: libgdx, box2d, dispose

Could someone please help me understand how I can properly dispose a Box2D World and Debug Renderer?

I have a playscreen that has a world and renderer and I would like to dispose of these when I change to another screen as I do not need them anymore. I have included in my playscreen dispose with the following, and called this manually when an event has been triggered to change screen. At the moment by calling these dispose() methods my game is crashing. Must a game have to have a Box2D world and renderer at all times? What would 'EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION' mean?

```
@Override
public void dispose() {
    System.out.println("PlayScreen disposed.");
    world.dispose();
    b2dr.dispose();
    ...
}
```

Comment: show some more code, like how you're changing screen and  also how and where you're using world, b2drenderer ?

Comment: i got b2drenderer to dispose() after destroying all the bodies in the their dispose methods. as for world, i created a new world in the play screen and passed world to objects to make bodies. i change my screen through this.
public void changeScreen() {
        game.setScreen(new GameOverScreen(game, hud));
        this.dispose();
    }

Comment: make sure you're not using world after disposing it, even from any other class.

Comment: i don't see world being used anywhere in the next screen. if other classes use world, if i dispose them before disposing world, i should be able to dispose world correct?

Comment: A game doesn't HAVE to have a box2d world/renderer at all times. Your error is likely due to something trying to use the world after you've disposed it, you need to follow your logic. For example, I know the sample libgdx game on the wiki has a lot of code in it's sample render() method. You're not by chance doing game logic inside render and calling changeScreen() in your render method and then trying to render the world after the changeScreen call? That would have the effect of disposing your world/renderer, setting the next screen but your render() keeps executing, tries to render and BOOM

Comment: you are right, i have an update method that's ultimately called by render. i think i understand the problem how the game logic is continuously called in render. if the game logic/calling changeScreen isn't in the render where should i call it? in show()? how will i update things without render().

Comment: Guessing at how your code is structured does not lend itself to providing a concrete answer. And even if you posted all your code, it could still be hard to deduce exactly how it works. But sounds like you are calling changeScreen within the render, which may be fine. My point was that you should render everything in your render method first, then have game logic AFTER the rendering. Such that if your game logic switches screens and disposes of the world, you have nothing left to render in your render method, as you already did it at the "top" of your render method.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience there are (at least) two situations where you can get an `EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION` in libGDX-box2d:

- `world.dispose` is called during `world.step`
- `world.dispose` is called from a different thread